# restore backup mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have a backup of my database in mysql of 250MB !!

How can I restore it in a new database on another server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing no detail on what operating system you're on and what kind of backup you have, but the short answer is

```
mysql -u username -p -h hostname databasename < dumpfile.sql
```

where `dumpfile.sql` needs to be a file containing SQL statements, for example produced with `mysqldump`.

Answer (score 2):

Or just use **phpMyAdmin** for restore porpoise.

Answer (score 1):

Using:

```
mysql -u USER -p -h HOST DATABASE < mysqldump.sql
```