# How to restore MySQL backup .sql on server

Tags: mysql

I'm using putty to connect to my MySQL server.

I've a backup .sql file from which I want to create the tables on the server.

According to the link here [restore backup mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892822/restore-backup-mysql), I'm trying to perform this command

`mysql -u username -p -h hostname databasename < dumpfile.sql`

Now my question is,

1. What is the 'hostname' here? Is it 'Localhost'?
2. How do I find the correct path to my `dumpfile.sql` file on the server which I have uploaded. Say for instance I've uploaded inside `www/apache/appname/`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are logged on to the machine where MySQL is running, `hostname` is indeed localhost (but if you leave it out, localhost is assumed).  For the path to `dumpfile.sql` you can just provide the full path including all folders.  Your question shows a relative path `www/apache/appname/`.  I assume that you meant that to be an absolute path starting from `/`.  If that's the case, the whole command would be

```
mysql -u username -p -h localhost databasename < /www/apache/appname/dumpfile.sql
```